.onContinueUserAcitivty / .onOpenURL not called when scanning QR-Code with NavigationStack
I have an app for which I've registered a custom url scheme (I know universal urls are preferred these days but this was a business decision).
Now, I want to open the app by scanning a QR-Code and then show the relevant view by reading the parameters from the url. Here's a sample link in the QR-Code:
my-schema://open-view/123

This is the code I'm working with right now:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var viewAction: ViewAction? = nil

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                SomeView(action: viewAction) // `viewAction` is being set in `handleOpenURL` and passes the retrieved data to subviews – works fine
                ...
            }
            .onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb) { userActivity in
                guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else { return }
                handleOpenURL(url)
            }
            .onOpenURL(perform: handleOpenURL)
        }
    }

As you can see, I'm using both .onContinueUserActivity and .onOpenURL. That's because sometimes, the former is called for QR-Code scanning and the latter for any tapped urls, and sometimes both call .onOpenURL – idk why.
Now, for navigation, I'm using a NavigationView and it all works fine. However, I'm experiencing some trouble with NavigationView, and since it's deprecated in favor for NavigationStack, I decided to switch to that.
When using NavigationStack, the app still opens fine from both a tapped link and a scanned QR-Code. However, neither .onContinueUserActivity or .onOpenURL are being called when scanning the QR-Code. Only when tapping on the link from the QR-Code, the methods are called.
TL;DR
when using NavigationStack, scanning a QR-Code to open the app does NOT call the methods I need to be called so I can retrieve the url parameters and open the respective view.
I have no idea what this has to do with the navigation method, but that's what I found.

Well what can I say, after switching to NavigationStack, then switching back to NavigationView, and then again switching to NavigationStack, it works...I guess the whole url schemes stuff is just unreliable :(
